# How to clear json cache from windows phone listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, json, caching, windows-phone-8

I am working on a windows phone 8 project and i am trying to solve this issue with json cache. I have 2 xaml pages in my project: 1st page contains Different football league (hyperlinks) and 2nd page is to display information about the league which was selected in 1st page.
My c# code is:

```
 ResultsList.ItemsSource = results.matches.Select(x => new
                {
                    away1 = x.match_visitorteam_name,
                    home1 = x.match_localteam_name,
                    homegoals1 = x.match_localteam_score,
                    awaygoals1 = x.match_visitorteam_score,
                    id1 = x.match_id,
                }).ToList();
```

My problem is when I click on 1st league on 1st pages,it forwards to second page and displays result but when I go back to 1st page and click on second league, it still shows contents from 1st league. My code is correct, I think issue is Json cache or something. Is there any way to clear this cache when I go back from second page? whats wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the phone caches the most recent call to save on data.

In your webservice call for the JSON append a random number on the end of the url

Something like this

```
Random ran = new Random();

webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.yoururl.com/yourJson.php?random=" + ran.Next().ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: No I'm not using webclient class. I've added web reference to my web service and created instance of that.

Comment: Is there a way to remove all json data when leaving a page?

Comment: There isn't a way that I am aware of to clear the cache. It's handled for you. However, I am sure there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
Client.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
```

or

```
WebClient.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

and still above doesnt work, use `HttpRequest` object instead of `WebClient`, and hopefully (if you place your doubts in `WebClient`) everything will be solved. If it wasn't solved with `HttpRequest`, then the problem really IS somewhere else.